# How to convert from string over to bool

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code, that when run, saves a string value True as seen here: 
[image]

Here is the code:

```
currentSetting = AppSession.Repository.Settings.Find(SettingQuery.ID == new ID("IsUsersLockedOut"));
            currentSetting[0].Value = true.ToString(); 
            AppSession.Repository.Settings.Save(currentSetting[0]);
```

My question today is how would I be able to get a boolean value back instead of the string value, the expected result should be when saved, the value == 1, instead of a string true in the picture above. Thank you all.

Comment: I can't decide if you're asking how to parse a string "true" to Boolean on the way out of a database, or save a string "1" into a database. Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: @CaiusJard Sorry for the vagueness, my goal was to parse a string 'true' to boolean

Comment: If you're trying to parse `"true"` or `"false"` to a `bool` you can just use [`Convert.ToBoolean(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toboolean). You'll get a `FormatException` if you pass something other than `"true"` or `"false"` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loads of ways to do this, here are a few:

```
    string boo = "true";

    bool b1 = Convert.ToBoolean(boo);
    bool b2 = bool.Parse(boo);
    bool b3 = bool.TryParse(boo, out var bParsed) && bParsed;
    bool b4 = boo.Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

The first two will explode if a non bool is passed. The third returns true only if something parsably boolean was passed otherwise false, and the fourth returns true only if some version of the word TruE was passed otherwise false